What is the minimal-rank permutation representation of Th
The smallest degree permutation representation of the sporadic Thomposon group is on 143127000 points, and the second smallest is on 283599225 points. The stabilizers are (respectively) the Steinberg group $^3D_4(2)\!:\!3$ and the Dempwolff group $2^5\!\cdot \!L_5(2)$.
I'm guessing that the representation on 143127000 points has the lowest rank, but I figured I'd mention the 283599225-point representation just in case. I would use the character tables of the relevant groups to determine the ranks of these representations, but I don't know which conjugacy classes in $^3D_4(2)\!:\!3$ correspond to which conjugacy classes in the Thompson group, and I don't know the character table of $2^5\!\cdot \!L_5(2)$ at all. Links to this information could be helpful, but ultimately, I'm just asking for the ranks of these permutation representations.

Using GAP's character table library:
gap> c:=CharacterTable("th");
CharacterTable( "Th" )
gap> m:=List(Maxes(c),CharacterTable);
[ CharacterTable( "3D4(2).3" ), CharacterTable( "2^5.psl(5,2)" ),
  CharacterTable( "2^1+8.a9" ), CharacterTable( "U3(8).6" ),
  CharacterTable( "(3xG2(3)):2" ), CharacterTable( "ThN3B" ),
  CharacterTable( "ThM7" ), CharacterTable( "3^5:2S6" ),
  CharacterTable( "5^(1+2):4S4" ), CharacterTable( "5^2:4s5" ),
  CharacterTable( "7^2:(3x2S4)" ), CharacterTable( "L2(19).2" ),
  CharacterTable( "L3(3)" ), CharacterTable( "A6.2_3" ),
  CharacterTable( "31:15" ), CharacterTable( "A5.2" ) ]
gap> pc:=List(m,x->Induced(x,c,Irr(x){[1]})[1]);; # induce trivial => permchar
gap> List(pc,x->ScalarProduct(c,x,x));  # ranks are given by inner products
[ 11, 11, 38, 165, 237, 103267, 103178, 742266, 630190297, 630200602,
  1822687218, 1939872980, 2877268098, 175050415998, 419682944190,
  6301805704620 ]

So the two smallest degree representations both have rank 11.
